# Importing overhead

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have functions and I feel like they should be a single group:

```js
import { first, second, third, fourth, fifth } from './some-file'
```

Im thinking to add them as methods in order to simplify importing:

```js
const parent = {
   first: () => // ...
   second: () => // ...
   // etc
}
```

Now my importing would be more convenient:

```js
import parent from './some-file'

// Usage
parent.first()
```

All `first`, `second` *etc* are already used in many, many different files and included to bundle.

However, they are sometimes used together in same file and sometimes not which means that most of the methods are "dragging along".

**Does it have any serious impact or effects?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider doing `import * as parent from './some-file';`. See http://es6-features.org/#ValueExportImport for reference. No further changes are needed